# Netty's HttpObjectAggregator appears to miss HTTP chunks

Tags: java, json, http, netty, chunked-encoding

I'm working on an asynchronous HTTP client using the Netty framework in Java and am having some troubles related to chunked encoding. The client is connecting to a REST service which emits JSON responses which can be accessed via long polling. The server responds using chunked encoding, so I'm utilizing Netty's `HttpObjectAggregator` to re-assemble the chunks before handling each response. The problem I'm having is that for about 1/2 of the long poll requests, my HTTP handler gets only a partial JSON response. Usually issuing the same request once or twice results in the full request being provided.

**Steps I've taken to solve the problem:**

1. Use `HttpContentDecompressor`
2. Netty versions 5.0.0.Alpha2, 4.1.0.Beta5, 4.0.29.Final
3. Removed the possibility that the `HttpContentDecompressor` was not 'large' enough, by giving it ample room to hold the response

**Things I don't know**

4. If Netty is really the issue: this could just be a terrible web service, but it is encrypted with SSL and I don't know how to log the raw responses from Netty before they get assembled
5. Why this only happens for some of the requests. Usually retrying once or twice for the same request solves the problem

**My goal: to reliably assemble the chunks into one single body.**

I'd really appreciate any advice for debugging this one!

**Edit**: As Bayou.io pointed out, I have the order of the chunked encoding reassembly and gzip inflation mixed up. However, I did also try this without the gzip encoding and the same error occurred.

**Some code:**

This is where I configure my HTTP client

```
/**
 * Establishes a connection, or throws an exception if one cannot be made
 * @throws Exception If there is a problem connecting to {@link #mUri}
 */
private void connect() throws Exception {
    mGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(mGroup)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                    /* all channel IO goes through the pipeline */
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

                    /* handles read timeout */
                    p.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(mTimeout));

                    /* handles SSL handshake if needed */
                    if (mUri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
                        p.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc(), mUri.getHost(), mUri.getPort()));

                    /* converts to HTTP response */
                    p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());

                    /* decompress GZIP if needed */
                    p.addLast(new HttpContentDecompressor());

                    /* aggregates chunked responses */
                    p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

                    /* handles response for child class */
                    configureCustomPipelines(p, mCallback);
                }

            });

    mChannel = b.connect(mUri.getHost(), mUri.getPort()).sync().channel();
}
```

The handler configured in `configureCustomPipelines` is the following class (unnecessary details omitted):

```
public abstract class BaseHttpHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {
    ...    
    /**
     * Processes the response and ensures that the correct callback is invoked,
     * and then that the HttpClient is shutdown
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) {
        if (!mHandled) {
            if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
                HttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
                int status = response.status().code();

                if (status < 200 || status > 299) {
                    handleBadResponse(response, status);
                    mHandled = true;
                } else {
                    HttpContent content = (HttpContent) msg;
                    String body = content.content().toString(
                            0,
                            content.content().writerIndex(),
                            CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

                    if (body.length() > 0) {
                        handleMessageBody(body, status);
                        mHandled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (mHandled)
            shutdown(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        shutdown(ctx);
    }

    private void shutdown(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.channel().close();
        ctx.channel().eventLoop().shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

I know the response is cut short because the handler function below is unable to parse the JSON body. Upon further inspection, it appears that the JSON string ends abruptly:

```
if (body.length() > 0) {
        handleMessageBody(body, status);
        mHandled = true;
}
```

Comment: not sure but should the order be switched between gzip and chunked?

Comment: @bayou.io, thank you for pointing this out. I will certainly be switching the order of the chunked encoding reassembly and gzip inflation. I found more information on this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding "...in case both compression and chunked encoding are enabled, the chunk encoding itself is not compressed, and the data in each chunk should not be compressed individually. The remote endpoint can decode the incoming stream by first decoding it with the Transfer-Encoding, followed by the specified Content-Encoding."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to determine that Netty was not the problem. It turns out that the HTTP server was periodically failing to send some of the responses. I was able to determine this using a custom stream dump handler in the pipeline that wrote the (post-ssl decryption) contents received by Netty to files. After manually inspecting these, the issue was clear.